# Style CZML paths thinner and with shade to ground

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to display a GPS tracklog in my Cesium application. But I can't get a nice styling for the path working. What I want it to look like:

[image]

What it currently looks like:

[image]

This is how I style the path currently:

```
path : {
  width : 2,
  leadTime : 0,
  resolution : 5,
  material : {
    polylineOutline : {
      color : {
          rgba : [255, 0, 0, 255]
      }
    },
  },
},
```

What I want to have:

1. Thin colored lines without black blurry "outlines" (see second image and compare with first).
2. A faded area that marks the elevation above ground for the first section of the path.

---

SOLUTION:

For 1.) I now found a pretty similar solution thanks to emackey:

```
path : {
show : true,
leadTime : 0,
trailTime : 60,
width : 2.5,
resolution : 1,
material : new Cesium.PolylineGlowMaterialProperty({
    glowPower : 15,
    taperPower : 0.0001,
    color : Cesium.Color.fromBytes(349, 66, 68, 255)
})
}
```

For 2.) I still haven't found what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in effect exactly like that first screenshot you posted from [Ayvri](https://ayvri.com/) (formerly Doarama), but, the most similar built-in thing could be the "tapered line" effect added earlier this year to Cesium:

Here's [a demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=HeadingPitchRoll.html).  Click in the Cesium window and use the arrow keys to steer the aircraft.

[image: Tapered glowing lines]

These are the path settings from the demo:

```
path : {
    show : true,
    leadTime : 0,
    trailTime : 60,
    width : 10,
    resolution : 1,
    material : new Cesium.PolylineGlowMaterialProperty({
        glowPower : 0.3,
        taperPower : 0.3,
        color : Cesium.Color.PALEGOLDENROD
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, emackey!
This kind of looks better than the normal one, but only when used with white-ish colors. In different colors I get ugly artefacts: https://i.imgur.com/6v8ZOlM.png

If I want to implement similar paths (in terms of smooth lines without pixelate outlines, shades that clamp to ground) as Ayvri uses, how could I do that with Cesium? Unfortunately I can't find anything on the internet. :(

Comment: With the "PolylineGlow" you have to set a much thicker line width.  The demo above uses 10 pixel wide lines.  It needs to be wide enough to hold both the bright area and the faded fringes, that's why you're seeing those artifacts.  You can control the apparent width by adjusting the glowPower setting.

Comment: The shading that goes to the ground is some other effect.  I'm not sure what that is, maybe a WallGeometry with a custom shader or something on it.  Sorry I don't know what they did for that one.

Comment: Thanks! I've now found a pretty similar soution for 1.).
I've wrote it down in my initial question.